# Prolog: zip 2 lists into one

Tags: prolog

Suppose, we have 2 lists `[1, 2, 3]`, `[3, 2, 1]` and we want to create a third list equal to the result of a binary function applied to every corresponding pair of the lists elements.

Something like:

```
f(x, y) = 
    -1, if x < y; 
    0, if x = y; 
    1 if x > y.
```

For our example we get `[-1, 0, 1]`.

I created the code:

```
f(A, B, C) :- ( A < B ->
                C = -1
              ; A =:= B ->
                C = 0
              ; C = 1
              ).

zip([A], [B], [C]) :- f(A, B, C).
zip([A | T1], [B | T2], [C | T]) :- f(A, B, C), zip(T1, T2, T).
```

It works:

```
?- zip([1,2,3], [3,2,1], X).
X = [-1, 0, 1] .
```

But I have a feeling that I am reinventing the wheel. Is there a system function for this in Prolog?

Comment: What about `zip([], Ys, Zs)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a `maplist` predicate
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/4

just like so

```
?- maplist(f,[1,2,3],[3,2,1],C).
C = [-1, 0, 1].
```